# Error in a predicate with expression function

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, predicate

I'm using an expression function for predicate in LINQ Where method (that returns IQueryable result) which takes a class parameter:

```
    public ActionResult FilterProfiles(FilterViewModel filter)
    {
        var profiles = database.Profiles
            .Where(Predicate(filter))
            ...
    }
```

The predicate is:

```
    private static Expression<Func<UserProfile, bool>> Predicate(FilterViewModel f)
    {
       return p => (CompareFilter(p, f));
    }
```

The problem is with the CompareFilter function:

```
    private static bool CompareFilter(UserProfile profile, FilterViewModel filter)
    {
        if (filter.FirstName != null)
        {
            if (profile.FirstName != null)
            {
                if (profile.FirstName.CompareTo(filter.FirstName) != 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
       ...
      }
```

The exception is:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean CompareFilter(Project.Models.UserProfile, Project.Web.ViewModels.FilterViewModel)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

**Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean CompareFilter(Project.Models.UserProfile, Project.Web.ViewModels.FilterViewModel)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're attempting to use a method in the lambda being translated by Entity Framework.

Entity Framework is actually using `IQueryable`s to translate your method calls into SQL as you call them, to make querying a database seamless. This means, however, that any method *you* define is inherently outside the purview of Entity Framework, and it therefore cannot translate it into SQL, and thus fails. Even though you know the source, the `Expression` functions cannot access a compiled method as an expression tree.

A workarounf for this (and many other similar situations) is to use `.AsEnumerable()` which will cause further Linq calls to be the `IEnumerable` versions, which enumerate via `foreach` and thus pull our objects into memory.